# Browser back button doesn't work and doesn't change the value in state

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-router-dom, semantic-ui-react

I am working on a project which uses backend API to fetch data and display on the frontend using react. I am not a react professional but learning by working on a project, Since the last 3 months I am stuck on one problem and still couldn't figure out how can it be solved.
This is the format of data that I receive

```
{
"data": [],
"meta": {
"page": 1,
"total": 382,
"per_page": 10,
"total_pages": 39,
"search_query": {},
"message": ""
}
}
```

This is how the URL looks like

```
const url = `${
    CONSTANTS.BASE_URL
  }/jobs?page=${counter}&position=${searchField.toLowerCase()}&city=${locationField.toLowerCase()}&job_type=${jobType}`;
```

I am using `useHistory` from `react-router-dom` to show dynamic url on the browser.

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
let jobHistory = useHistory();
```

This is how I pushed the URL into browser to look it dynamic

```
useEffect(() => {
    searchJobs(setIsLoading, setData, setMeta, url);
    setToggleSearch(false);
    jobHistory.push(
      `?page=${counter}${searchField ? `&position=${searchField.toLowerCase()}` : ''}${
        locationField ? `&city=${locationField.toLowerCase()}` : ''
      }${jobType ? `&job_type=${jobType}` : ''}`
    );
  }, [counter, jobType, toggleSearch]);
```

This is how `searchJobs` is being implemented

```
export default async (setIsLoading, setData, setMeta, url) => {
  try {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const res = await fetchData(url);
    setData(res.data);
    setMeta(res.meta);
    setIsLoading(false);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

I have a pagination component that I implemented using [Semantic UI react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/addons/pagination/).
This is how I have controlled the value of `counter`

```
 {meta && meta.total > 0 && <CustomPagination meta={meta} setCounter={setCounter} />}
```

by passing it inside the `CustomPagination` Component, which looks like this.

```
const CustomPagination = ({ meta, setCounter }) => {
  const pageChange = (e, { activePage }) => {
    setCounter(activePage);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="pagination">
        {meta && meta.total_pages && meta.total_pages > 1 && (
          <Pagination
            defaultActivePage={meta.page}
            onPageChange={pageChange}
            firstItem={false}
            lastItem={false}
            prevItem={{ content: <Icon name="angle left" />, icon: true }}
            nextItem={{ content: <Icon name="angle right" />, icon: true }}
            totalPages={meta.total_pages}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default CustomPagination;
```

Here comes the problem:

- Pagination works pretty well when I just press the Pagination numbers and it displays correct value in the URL, but when I press the back button, the URL changes the value but the output on the page remains the same. **This problem occurs by clicking on normal pagination or by searching using keywords, I mean in both cases**.
- The second case, if I go to `page number 6` by clicking on pagination, it displays me 10 jobs result on that page and URL looks something like this `?page=6` and after I click on individual jobs `/jobs/23499` and try to come back using the browser back button, the URL again takes me to the 1st page `?page=1`.
- The third case, As a user I want to go to page 8 just by renaming the page number at URL, If I try to do so, again it redirects me to `?page=1`

In my opinion, all the problems are caused by the wrong way of handling the value of the `counter`. Being a beginner, I couldn't figure out how it can be implemented correctly. Just to make sure, I have posted my whole code in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/20was/40f6ac5cd9164a70f0b576d487ba7990) or you can see the problem live [here](https://app.autechjobs.ml/), just need to signup first. Any help would be more than appreciated. Thank you all developers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In essence, the react-router-dom history is implemented with a stack data structure. If you want to go forward you “push” a url onto the stack and when you want to go back you perform a “pop” operation. From your code example, it looks like you use the history hook to get you to your pagination view but then you don’t update your stack when you paginate.

Solution:
Looks like you need to push your new urls with the updated query parameter during the onclick Event of your pagination. When you go back you can pop or use the history.goBack() function provided .

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Can you show me any code example?